# Capturing popups with Visual Studio Team webtests

Tags: visual-studio, webtest

We have a number of popups (generated using Javascript) that are displayed during page navigation.

When we record the webtest, the script doesn't capture all of them.

If there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load tests do no render javascript, but operate solely by recording individiual http requests. So no, there is no way around this.

Investigate the new [Visual Studio 2010 Coded UI test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) for testing the operation of the UI.

I think this is the tool for the job, however I do not have any experience with it.